# Smarty foreach loop output code every four items but only output the code a maximum of 3 times

Tags: foreach, smarty

Ok, so I have this code.

```
{foreach $listings as $id => $listing name=listing}

    {if $smarty.foreach.listing.iteration is div by 4}
        ADSENSE CODE
    {/if}

{/foreach}
```

What this does is it outputs Google adsense code every 4 items.

As you will be aware, Google adsense only allows 3 ads per page so I require it to break after showing the ad 3 times.

After many fruitless Google searches, I am stumped!

Please help,

Regards.

Comment: There is - {break} but I tried  {if $smarty.foreach.listing.index == 3}{break}{/if} but that breaks the whole output..

Comment: how about  {break name="listing"}

Answer (score 1):

as far as i can see [here](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=63443)
you can use

```
{break}
```

and it should work

also, you can have a counter and

```
{foreach $listings as $id => $listing name=listing}
    {if $smarty.foreach.listing.index <= 12}
       {if $smarty.foreach.listing.iteration is div by 4}
          ADSENSE CODE
       {/if}
    {/if}

{/foreach}
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't.. I did however have a lightbulb moment and have answered my own question.. Thank you for your time anyway :)

Comment: @DanielCheeseman anytime. you can put your answer here anyway

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after looking at the code I had an epiphany.

I only want to show the ad 3 times so I did this and it works like a charm.

```
{foreach $listings as $id => $listing name=listing}

    {if $smarty.foreach.listing.index == 4}

        ADSENSE CODE

    {/if}

    {if $smarty.foreach.listing.index == 8}

        ADSENSE CODE

    {/if}

    {if $smarty.foreach.listing.index == 12}

        ADSENSE CODE

    {/if}

{/foreach}
```